# How can I retrieve a record from a SQL database into my program using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

How can I retrieve a record from a SQL database into my program using c#?
My database name is lightsandsounds, the name of the table is tbl_reservation, and I would like to get the value of the field fld_number into the textbox1 of my program.  Your answers would be great help. Thank you.

Comment: You can start by writing some code.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index.html

Comment: We don't provide code, we help you with the code you already have.

Comment: It's scary by the looks of the table name tbl_reservation .. hopefully not for an airlines.. Cause I would not be flying on it..

Comment: @TejaswiRana No no, that's where you put your reservations about the airline. Sounds to me like you're having reservations already

Comment: Hahahahahahhhaa .. there.. enuff characters to post this comment..

Comment: Aww, the question has been put on hold. I was actually typing up a real answer to it, too.

Comment: @cost try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239626/binding-listt-with-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Start by using these...

A keyboard
[image]

[image]
and a mouse..

Comment: Where can I get one of those overly colorful keyboards

Comment: Now that's a good question..

Comment: Looks like you can buy them here http://www.keyright.com/ except, they have some kind of ipad related popup ad that can't actually be closed...

Comment: I can see the product, now if only that stupid popup would go away so I can `click` it

Comment: Day = Made. I can go home now.

Comment: Why would you want to go home now? How about booking a flight or a room? All you need is a textbox and a SQL database..

Comment: I think we should upvote the question and make it a wiki thing..

Comment: @Ben and at cost.. there's another walker.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239626/binding-listt-with-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Comment: @TejaswiRana Another walker.. you mean like a zombie? I think that's a better question than this one by far, what am I looking for there?

Comment: @Cost yeah we're not allowed to call "zombies". That question is like I got something working, how about I write more lines of code to make it look like I solved something.

Comment: @TejaswiRana You can call the Zack, too. I don't think that's a bad question. When two things appear to act the same way, it's nice to have an idea of it something under the hood is acting differently. I've had a few problems to mop up at my current job because of people not understanding that sort of thing. All the same, that sort of thing is usually easy to google, but I often find a helpful SO page with the answer