# Binding List<T> with datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know what is the difference between binding list directly to datagridview datasource and binding Bindingsource to datagridview. Here is example:

Ex1:

```
List<Employee> list = this.GetEmployees();
dgvEmployees.Datasource = list;
```

Ex2:

```
List<Employee> list = this.GetEmployees();
BindingSource soure = new BindingSource();
soure.Datasource = list;
dgvEmployees.Datasource = soure;
```

So, which one should be the good practice?

Comment: If I had to pick.. and provided they both work, the first one.. half the lines of code and easier to read. Edit.. the second one looks really ugly.. a = b; c = a; plus I'd type soure as source.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433281/c-sharp-datagridview-datasource-difference-between-using-bindingsource-and-not

Answer (score 2):

In general, using `Datasource` directly is for simple cases and using a `BindingSource` is for more complex cases.  When all you want to do is display data and don't really care about modifying it before it's displayed, feel free to use `Datasource`

`BindingSource` on the other hand, allows you to (not an exhaustive list):

- Specify a `Format` method to transform the list data before the user sees it, and a `Parse` method to transform the list data back after the user edits it
- Track the *Current* (selected) item in the list
- Customize the way a new element is added
- Prevent edits to the current item
- Be notified when an element is added or removed